# Change the Focus From one Gridview cell to another without pressing any Key in c#

Tags: datagridview, windows

I am using DataGridView to add/edit data. My DataGridView has 2 columns. I will add data to Column1 through Barcode Scanner(USB). But my point is - I want to change the focus form one cell to next alternative cell(means Row1->cell-1 to Row2->Cell-1...) without pressing any key. It should happen after Barcode Scanner Scanned the Barcode & display Barcode on the cell.

Thanks
Marulasiddesha TN

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `CurrentCell` property of the `DataGridView` as shown below:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
```

Use that code withing the event handler for the barcode scanner and set the row and cell indexes to the right value.

You may also need to call the Focus() method of the `DataGridView` to ensure that it has focus for editing.

Comment: Thanks David,                                                        I do not have any event for Barcode Scanner. Barcode Scanner is Automatic, it looks only the focus.